# No Allow G-Sync option - NVidia Drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have Freesync monitor 240hz and geforce GTX 1650. Nvidia driver 455 and monitor connected via DP.
I don't have option "No Allow G-Sync on monitor not validated as G-sync compatible". Do you know why and any ideas how to enable it?

[My Nvidia settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHPZ6.png)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use G-Sync with a FreeSync display.  They are both different types of adaptive sync.  They are not compatible with each other.

If you want to use the G-Sync feature of your NVIDIA card, you will need a G-Sync enabled display.

FreeSync only works with a compatible FreeSync display and a compatible AMD GPU.